# Why can't Pascal's Simplex with n terms be used to describe close-packing of equal n-spheres?

Tags: geometry, simplex, packing-problem

[Pascal's simplex](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pascal%27s_simplex) is a generalization of Pascal's triangle into n dimensions, just as multinomial theorem is a generalization of binomial theorem. In Pascal's triangle, binomial coefficients are arranged in the close-packing arrangement for circles. In Pascal's pyramid, trinomial coefficients are arranged in *a* close-packing arrangement for spheres (there are multiple in 3 dimensions). This is also true for 1-dimensional spheres (aka line segments).
My intuition is that this pattern would continue infinitely, but I know that doesn't mean anything, especially as a layperson.

I should also point out that each the close-packing arrangement for spheres has cross-sections that look like the close-packing arrangement for circles, which has cross-sections that look like line segments stacked together, which is the close-packing arrangement in 1 dimension.

Are these apparent patterns just a coincidence?

If I've gotten anything wrong, please let me know.

Comment: The Leech lattice will blow your mind. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Leech_lattice

Comment: @GerryMyerson I don't see how that helps answer my question, except maybe that there are ways to construct the Leech lattice based on close-packing patterns in lower dimensions.

Comment: The Leech lattice gives a close packing in 24 dimensions. You can use it to test your theory about cross-sections looking like close packing one dimension down.

Comment: I don't have the skills or knowhow to do that.

Comment: I'm having trouble finding a clear-enough source to post an answer, but I think the optimal packing for 4d is based on the 24-cell, and not the simplex, so that your idea fails in one higher dimension than the "pyramid". Also, this question really has little to do with Pascal/the multinomial theorem. It's just about simplices and packing.

Comment: @MarkS. I was asking they were connected. That's why I put those tags. I brought up multinomial theorem to briefly describe Pascal's simplex, because that's what Pascal's simplex is analogous to.